# Refresh the UI due to a change in model

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

How do we refresh the UI of the activity to reflect the changes to Model.

I have two activities called **DonorDetailActivity** and **DonorEditActivity**.

Both represent a model called **Donor** which is a plain object. From the **DonorDetailActivity** **startActivityForResult()** is executed for getting to the **DonorEditActivity**. In the **DonorEditActivity** after the **Donor** (model) is edited, we are back on the **DonorDetailActivity**. Following show the flow

```
MainAcitvity ==>> DonorListActivity ==> DonorDetailActivity ==> DonorEditActivity
```

Here is the activity code that I am using (neglecting the Main and List activity)

**DonorDetailActivity**

```
public class DonorDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private View detailView;
    private Donor donor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        donor = (Donor) bundle.getSerializable("DONOR");

        detailView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_donor_detail,null);

        TextView txvUserId = (TextView) detailView.findViewById(R.id.txvUserId);
        txvUserId.setText(donor.getUserId());

        //Other properties of Donor ......

        Button btnEditDonor = (Button) detailView.findViewById(R.id.btnEditDonor);
        btnEditDonor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent donorEditIntent = new Intent(DonorDetailActivity.this, DonorEditActivity.class);
                donorEditIntent.putExtra("DONOR", donor);
                startActivityForResult(donorEditIntent, DONOR_EDIT_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == DONOR_EDIT_REQUEST) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    donor = (Donor) data.getSerializableExtra("DONOR");
                    //ToDo refresh screen with edited Donor object
                    //How to do this
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DonorEditActivity**

```
public class DonorEditActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AsyncTaskCallback<String> {

    private static final int DONOR_EDIT_REQUEST = 1;
    private View editView;
    private Donor donor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
    }

    //Donor edit complete. Return to Detail Class with modified Donor object

    @Override
    public void onAsyncTaskCompleted(String result) {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent();
        detailIntent.putExtra("DONOR", donor); //Modified Donor object
        if (result == null || result.length() == 0){
            setResult(RESULT_OK, detailIntent);
        }
        else {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, detailIntent);
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

So, how do I refresh the UI when I am back into the **DonorDetailActivity** with a modified **Donor** object.

Comment: Finish and restart the DonorDetailActivity?

Comment: Does work, but I was confused that finish() would actually stop the execution of code, and return to the previous activity. But it does go on to execute the next line of starting the DonorDetailActivity again. Certainly works!

Comment: `finish()` closes the Activity. So, when you restart it, it's loaded brand new, with the updated details.

Comment: why you are not just rebinding the model and the view. let's say that in `onCreate` you are finding all your views and then binding the model and the view. move the binding method `bindModelView` and just run this method @ `onActivityResult`

Comment: Yes that is also a solution. I had that in mind, but since I am new to android programming, I asked the community for their approaches of refreshing the screen. @DerGolem's solution worked, so I didn't try to modify my code to extract the layout code in a separate bindModelView method and invoke it as required. But I think your solution should work too.

Comment: I posted my coments as an answer, so you can accept it and remove it from the Unanswered Questions Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finishing and restarting the DonorDetailActivity will work.

`finish()` closes the Activity.
So, when you restart it, it's loaded brand new, with the updated details.